# Eliminate Render Blocking Resources Google PageSpeed Insight

Tags: javascript, css, optimization, mobile, google-pagespeed

I'm trying to improve Mobile Speed in Google PageSpeed Insight. Here is the link to the result: https://rb.gy/x6rppd

I'm using SG Optimizer, Autoptimize already to minify, combine css and js already. Can anyone please help?

Comment: The report [links to a page explaining render blocking resources](https://web.dev/render-blocking-resources/?utm_source=lighthouse&utm_medium=unknown), [this article is a good starting point for beginners on critical CSS](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/08/understanding-critical-css/) and here is [further info on render blocking CSS](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css). At the moment you haven't actually asked a question we can answer so have a read and then ask some questions if you get stuck and we can help then

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm actually trying to improve Mobile Speed but as you can see it has very low score and FCP is not good at all. Also, if you check there are a lot of unused Javascript and CSS.

Comment: There is a lot to optimisation, the main reasons for your slow FCP are that you haven't inlined your critical CSS (that is CSS that is needed to display the initial page content "above the fold"). As such the browser has to wait for the CSS file to be downloaded before it can start rendering. Because you have combined your CSS this file is large and so takes a long time to download. Read the articles I linked as you need a base understanding before we can offer any guidance. Also at 8.5MB your page is very heavy so you need to look into removing page weight. Finally 108 requests is a lot.

Comment: I would suggest that you open each item that Lighthouse reports on (both in the "opportunities" section and the "diagnostics" section) and having a read of what that section is about. You can do this by just clicking on the item. With a basic understanding you can ask specific questions and we can help better, as it stands you are basically asking us to optimise the site for you (from a very bad starting position). It takes a while to learn enough to know where problems but just start reading and you will get it I promise.

Comment: Okay. After reading and doing everything I found that there is "iconsmind.woff" font under Enormous Network Payout Load i.e. 1,150.8 KiB. How can I remove this font?
My CSS and JS are around 140Kb so I don't think this is causing the problem here.

Comment: That looks to be commented out, have you done that since your comment? Whatever you are using from facebook (guessing it is messenger) is adding about 300kb (gzipped) to your page. You should look at adding a decent delay before initialising that so the scripts are downloaded later. Also there seem to be a lot of duplicate requests (facebook being one, your vimeo player being another)  so look into how to load the player "on intent", by which I mean show the thumbnail as a static image and only load the actual player when you click on that thumbnail. That would save another 250kb js & 30kb CSS

Comment: I don't think it's commented out as I can still see that font under Enormous Payout Load. I could find a way to lazyload the vimeo and will update it. However, I'm unable to figure out what plugin is being used in my Wordpress for Facebook Messenger lol. I don't know what the heck my developer did for that.

Comment: Alright it turns out the Facebook Messenger was because of ManyChat script in my child theme. It's defined as:

<script src="//widget.manychat.com/425655531590175.js" async="async"></script>